# Disable and enable back binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some textbox that binded to `MyText` in code behind, I need the following:

```
if(x)
  //disable binding of textbox
if(y)
  //enable back binding'
```

I know that it is possible to **cancel** binding like this:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(MyTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty)
```

but how to disable and then enable back? is it possible?

Comment: Do you have Xaml for this ?

Comment: Something like `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"/>`

Comment: Umm, do you have any events while something is changed in textbox like button appearing etc?

Comment: plz post answers

Comment: what exactly you want to acheive by ClearBinding and to enable binding later. do you want your textbox to show empty while condition is met or something there can be another better solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "disable" or "pause" a binding temporarily. You will have to remove the binding and then create a new binding afterwards:

```
if (x)
    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(MyTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
else if (y)
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("MyText"));
```

There is no other or better way as far as the binding mechanism is concerned.

You shouldn't have to clear the binding in the first place though.